# Laravel: Hide View Data chunk based on user Id

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So I have Blade that displays $data with array of menu items:

```
$data = [
    [
        'icon' => 'pie-chart',
        'name' => 'Example',
        'url' => request()->root()...,
        'permission' => true,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'Example',
        'icon' => 'users',
        'name' => 'Example',
        'permission' => true,
        'subMenu' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Example',
                'url' => request()->root()...,
                'permission' => true,
            ],
```

I want to display them Based on Condition. For example I have

```
        if (1 !== Auth::id()) {
            // dislpay the chunk of data from above
        }
```

And Also do i need to import "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;" ? in blade?

Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest filtering menu items inside a [Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers) or Service.
I'd leave the leave as simple as possible.

Controller example:

```
public function index()
{
    $menuItems = $this->filterMenuItemsBasedOnAuthRole(
        $this->getMenuItems()
    );
    return view()->with(['menuItems' => $menuItems]);
}

private function getMenuItems()
{
    return ['your_full' => 'menu'];
}

private function filterMenuItemsBasedOnAuthRole(array $items)
{
    $hasAccess = Auth::user()->id === 1;

    // logic that filters your menu items

    return $items;
}
```

Then your view would simply display the menu items, not worrying about filtering at all.

```
@foreach($menuItems as $menuItem)
    {{ $menuItem }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for ur time, so does this cover the part where I want some menu items to display and some not? (for users with not the id 1)

Comment: That's the filtering that you would need to code yourself in `filterMenuItemsBasedOnAuthRole`.

You would need to set which menu items are protected in `getMenuItems`, then iterate over them in `filterMenuItemsBasedOnAuthRole` and filter out menu items that the user does not have access to.

Comment: Ah, Got it now ! Im gonna give it a shot :)

Comment: Hmm, no luck with this method.Do you think it is possible to implement straight into the blade? something like, @if (Auth::id() ==!) part of the data and else the other part. Is this doable this way?

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to do it in blade file itself. I added second array that displays only the fields i want to show for non admin users like $data1 for admin data2 for non admins. Then used `@if (auth()->check()) @if (auth()->user()->isAdmin())` this bit to check if user was admin or not and displayed $data1 or data2 accordingly. Hope it helps someone out there.